# Efficiency of explicit initialization

Tags: c++, performance, initialization, explicit

I have a class which has a constructor that takes a `const char*`. It is:

```
c::c(const char* str) {
    a = 32;
    f = 0;
    data = new char[strlen(str)];
    memcpy(data, str, strlen(str));
}
```

And a function which takes one of them:

```
int foo(c& cinst);
```

You can call this function either by passing it an instance of a `c`:

```
c cinst("asdf");
foo(cinst);
```

or, because we have explicit initialization, you can do:

```
foo("asdf");
```

which will make a `c` by passing the constructor "asdf" and then pass the resulting object to `foo`.

However, this seems like it might be quite a bit less efficient than just overloading `foo` to take a `const char*`. Is it worth doing the overload for the speed or is the performance impact so small that it's a waste of space to make an overload? I'm trying to make my program as fast as possible, so speed is an important factor, so is size, but not so much.

Comment: You aren't copying the `\0` terminator which is very likely an error. Also, you are calling `strlen` twice, which goes against your goal of being as fast as possible ;) I suggest the following: `data = new char[strlen(str) + 1]; strcpy(data, str);`.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Schlemiel the Painter? Google for it :) After that look at your calls to `strlen`

Comment: @Mac: Calling `strlen` twice is not quite as bad as calling it n times ;)

Comment: The example constructor isn't the actual constructor, it's an example. And no, not copying the null terminator is not an error.

Comment: @Thomas: How will your class know how long the string is if you don't terminate it and don't store the length somewhere? Also, have you followed the rule of three, i.e. have you written a destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator?

Comment: Because my class is an implementation (correct word?) of Pascal strings which store the length of the string. I need them because I want to store data which has NULLs in it. And yes, I have written the destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Both `std::string` and `std::vector<char>` can store `\0` characters. You are probably better off using one of those.

Comment: What's the fun in using somebody elses? :) Also, how do you store NULLs in a std::string? And mine is specifically made for it so it doesn't rely on arguments passed to it (like `append`, etc) to be NULL-terminated `char*`s, so it's a bit easier to use.

Comment: @Thomas: You get well-tested, well-documented code, and every C++ developer knows and understands `std::string` and `std::vector<char>`. If chasing bugs and explaining your undocumented class to other developers sounds like fun, go ahead... whatever floats your boat.

Comment: So you automatically assume my code will have lots of bugs and be undocumented. For shame. Also, mine is also consistently significantly faster at appending strings 100 times:  
std::string: 0.014079,  
my string: 0.002560  
:) Oh and you didn't answer the question on how to store NULLs in std::string.

Comment: @Thomas: `std::string s; s.push_back('\0');`

Comment: Yeah, that's more than a little inconvenient if you have something like a UDP packet which contains a lot of NULLs.

Comment: `char array[] = "foo\0bar\0baz"; std::vector<char> vec(array, array + 11);` There you go. About the performance, it's extremely unlikely that you can beat a well-optimized library string type by a factor of 5. Did you profile in debug mode by any chance? In that case, the measured results are meaningless.

Comment: Nope, not in debug mode. I find it a little hard to believe myself. The find method of my class also beats the std::string's find into the dust. It beats it very badly even when doing find 100000 times when std::string is still doing 100. I'm not sure if I believe that, but I checked and I'm doing everything right.

Comment: Oh, and that's a std::vector, not a std::string. How do you do it with string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will `foo` be doing with that `const char*`?  If it's just going to make it own `c` object, then there's no point.

If it is going to use the `char*` directly (and the existing `foo` just pulled the `char*` out of the `c` object), then it would be better to write an overload.

Answer (score 0):

It won't take zero time so it is one of the tradeoffs you have to take, speed versus api clarity.  Of course it will depend on what you are doing in your function that takes a const char*, are you constructing a c object?  In which case just offer the function with the c class interface.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of question is best answered with a profiler.
Looking at the assembler code for it may also provide a clue.

Answer (score 0):

It's situational. It really depends on just how much is really going on inside a constructor in a given situation and how many times that code is actually being executed.

In the example you give, those are pretty trivial operations in that constructor. On any reasonable modern processor those operations are going to be very very quick. So unless that code is being executed a huge number of times per second or more, then I wouldn't even worry about it. (Of course the value of "huge" depends on what kind of machine you expect to run this on. For this constructor, on a typical desktop processor, I wouldn't even begin to worry until it gets up into the scale of at least hundreds-of-thousands of times per second.)

If this construction code does run some huge number of times, then you still ought to profile it and determine for sure if it's having a noticeable impact compared to everything else going on in your program. Optimization is a tricky thing. Sometimes what your gut feeling says is inefficient actually has little impact on the end results. Measurement is always to way to determine where you should actually be spending your time to most effectively make your program run faster.